# Is there a name for the sum of the off-diagonal components of a tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, trace, convention

If you have a matrix, the "trace" of the matrix is the sum of the diagonal components of the matrix. For example, given a matrix $\mathbf{A}$:

$$\mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{bmatrix}$$

then the trace of $\mathbf{A}$ is:

$$\mathrm{trace}(\mathbf{A}) = a_{11}+a_{22}+a_{33}$$

**Is there a name for the "anti-trace" which sums the off-diagonal components?**

For example you could have the sum of the other diagonal across the matrix (from top right to bottom left):

$$\mathrm{some\_name}(\mathbf{A}) = a_{13}+a_{22}+a_{31}$$

Or you could have the sum of all elements of the matrix *except* the main diagonal elements:

$$\mathrm{some\_other\_name}(\mathbf{A}) = a_{12}+a_{13}+a_{21}+a_{23}+a_{31}+a_{32}$$

I am wondering if there is a name for these operations similar to "trace".

Thanks

Comment: I think no, because the trace has been given a name for it is an invariant of the linear operator or the tensor. If you change the coordinate system, the numerical representation (in your case, the matrix) changes, but the trace remains unperturbed. The same does not apply to the sum of other group of elements of the numerical representation (the matrix, in your case).

Comment: As @trying said, there probably isn't a name for this. However, there is a nice way to write the sum of all off-diagonal entries of $A$, namely $\text{tr}((J-I)A)$ where $J$ is the all-ones matrix.